# Add column to cross table generated by EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am developing a check in system with ASP.NET and Entity Framework. When you check in to a department you can select the activities you will use during your stay.

I have the following 2 model classes:

```
public class Department
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

Because it is a many-to-many relationship between departments and activities EF generates a cross table.

```
-----------------------------------
| # | Department_Id | Activity_Id |
-----------------------------------
```

I would like to add an extra column to the cross table called displayOrder, so each department can both select which activities they offer and the order they want to display them in.

```
--------------------------------------------------
| # | Department_Id | Activity_Id | DisplayOrder |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is this possible to do with EF or is there a better method. If it is possible how would you get a hold of the `displayOrder` attribute?

Comment: You need to handle on database layer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can make EF do it, but you could make a partial class of the cross table that contains the displayOrder attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you gonna need to create a model with your Department_Id ,Activity_Id  and DisplayOrder variables and the Relations they match with the object example:

```
public class DepartmentActivity
    {
        #region Public properties

        public int ActivityId{ get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId{ get; set; }
        public string DisplayOrder {get;set;} // this can be whatever you like and add more properties if needed

        #endregion

        #region Relations

        public Activity Activity{ get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

After that add to your DbSets this DepartmentActivity Class to represent your table and match it's relationships on the modelbuilder

```
    public DbSet<DepartmentActivity> DepartmentActivities { get; set; }


        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentActivity>().HasKey(x => new { x.ActivityId, x.DepartmentId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentActivity>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Activity).WithMany(x => x.Departments );
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentActivity>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Department).WithMany(x => x.Activities);
```

Just run the generate migration command from ef and should now have a table that works as intermediate table with more optional properties